# How to compare HDFS files with AWS S3 files using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We are having a replication between HDFS -> AWS S3 on a different replication tool (Wandisco), the challenge that we face is;

- Users often report that their data haven't received at their end
  (i.e) AWS S3. It is taking time to get it reflected in AWS S3. It is
  hard to traverse through the AWS S3 bucket to check through the data
  whether or not the data is not received.

So, we have thought and have been asked to build something with lambda to do check between HDFS and AWS S3 to see if the files are received or not perhaps, the last modified files etc and report it back via email or something. This way we wouldn't have any challenges connecting the AWS S3 bucket from any of our server, where we don't have Internet or Proxy, configuring it.

Please help me out on this also, suggest if there are any better solutions than this would be appreciated.

Thank you!